# How to use fontawsome icon as image?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, font-awesome

I receive this three information related to fontawesome icon.

How can I set this fontawesome icon as a profile image to a user in UWP C#?

```
background_color = rgb(220, 224, 231)
class = fa-alicorn
color = rgb(74, 74, 74)
```

Comment: Hi @saurav-kumar, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

It might be helpful to others if you include link to the fontawesome website from where you got this information.

Also, if you can show your code, it can help others understand what you meant by "profile image"...  :)

Comment: Is there any way to get fontawesome unicode using its class?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://www.blustemy.io/using-font-awesome-or-other-icon-fonts-in-xaml/) article and try to follow the steps mentioned there. Here is a snippet taken from there:

```
<Page …>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <HyperlinkButton Margin="0,0,32,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <FontIcon
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFlagString}"
                    FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Flag"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HyperlinkButton>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <FontIcon
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{StaticResource FontAwesomePaperPlaneString}"
                    FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Send"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```